# Printing multiple copies using ICoreWebView2's Print function

Tags: delphi, printing, webview2

I'm trying to print multiple copies of an HTML document using the `ICoreWebView2_16`'s [`Print()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2_16?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28#print) function.  The documentation states that "Only one Printing operation can be in progress at a time.".  I've tried using a for loop to print multiple times:

```
for I := 1 to NumberOfCopies do
      begin
          (EdgeBrowser.DefaultInterface as ICoreWebView2_16).Print(PrintSettings, CoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler);
      end;
```

This doesn't work because, as stated, only one print operation can happen at a time.

I've also tried using the `PrintSettings` parameter to indicate the number of copies, but there are no members for setting the number of copies in the [`ICoreWebView2PrintSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2printsettings?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28#summary) interface.  There **is** a member for settings the number of copies in the [`ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2printsettings2?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28)  interface...  But that can't be used as a parameter for the `ICoreWebView2_16.Print` function.

Comment: Just to note, if I use the `ShowPrintUI` function, the user can select the number of copies to print... but this doesn't work because it doesn't allow me to use my custom `PrintSettings`

Comment: What's `CoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler`? Wouldn't that be a perfect place to start the next of N print operation?

Comment: @AmigoJack After calling the Print function, `CoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler` stays nil forever.

Comment: `CoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler` is a [function expected to called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2_16?view=webview2-1.0.2045.28#print), not to be set. Since your example code doesn't include if it's a variable or a function I can only guess. Handing over a variable that you expect to be set (to what exactly?) is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an interesting challenge! I have put together a pure Delphi program that accomplishes this, using only pure Delphi (11.3) plus the WebView2_TLB.pas file generated by tlibimp.exe from a new enough version of WebView2 (1.0.1587.40 in my case).

The key insight is that if only the WebView2 installed is new enough, then functions that would *seem* to take an older version of an interface as parameter can often actually take also a *newer* version of that interface.

This is the case with the `ICoreWebView2_16.Print` function. Even though its declaration says that its parameter is "just" an `ICoreWebView2PrintSettings`, and not an `ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2`, you can still pass in an `ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2` -- if the installed version of WebView2 supports it.

There is a good example by Microsoft at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/blob/main/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print.md

I've adapted that to Delphi, and placed it on Github here - feel free to use that code and modify it further: https://github.com/bolligerm/delphi/tree/master/varia/GutenbergMini

I paste the core of the code here as well:

```
unit WebView2Print;

// This code by Matthias Bolliger is inspired by
// https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/blob/main/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/print.md

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  // Unit Winapi.WebView2 must come after WebView2_TLB in the uses list,
  // because any types defined in both those units (any overlap)
  // must lead to the type from Winapi.WebView2 being used,
  // because that's what TCustomEdgeBrowser uses
  WebView2_TLB,
  Winapi.WebView2,
  Vcl.Edge;

type
  TPrintStatus = (psSucceeded, psPrinterUnavailable, psOtherError, psUnknown);
  TCallWhenDonePrinting = procedure(ErrorCode: HResult; PrintStatus: TPrintStatus) of object;

procedure WebView2PrintCopies(EdgeBrowser: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
  Copies: Integer;
  Grayscale: Boolean;
  CallWhenDone: TCallWhenDonePrinting);


implementation

uses
  Winapi.ActiveX;

type
  TCompletedHandler = class(TInterfacedObject, ICoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler)
  private
    function Invoke(errorCode: HResult; printStatus: COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_STATUS): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

threadvar
  CallWhenDonePrinting: TCallWhenDonePrinting;

procedure WebView2PrintCopies(EdgeBrowser: TCustomEdgeBrowser;
  Copies: Integer;
  GrayScale: Boolean;
  CallWhenDone: TCallWhenDonePrinting);
var
  Core2: ICoreWebView2;
  Core2_16: ICoreWebView2_16;
  Environment: ICoreWebView2Environment;
  Environment6: ICoreWebView2Environment6;
  PrintSettings: ICoreWebView2PrintSettings;
  PrintSettings2: ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2;
  HR: HRESULT;
  CompletedHandler: ICoreWebView2PrintCompletedHandler;
begin
  // Remember the callback to call when we're done
  CallWhenDonePrinting := CallWhenDone;

  // Check that the currently installed version of WebView2
  // supports core interface version 16 (which has the Print support we need)
  EdgeBrowser.ControllerInterface.Get_CoreWebView2(Core2);
  if not Assigned(Core2) then
    raise Exception.Create('Get_CoreWebView2 not found');

  Core2.QueryInterface(IID_ICoreWebView2_16, Core2_16);
  if not Assigned(Core2_16) then
    raise Exception.Create('IID_ICoreWebView2_16 not found - necessary Print support lacking');

  // Check that the currently installed version of WebView2
  // supports environment interface version 6 (which has CreatePrintSettings)
  Environment := EdgeBrowser.EnvironmentInterface;

  Environment.QueryInterface(IID_ICoreWebView2Environment6, Environment6);
  if not Assigned(Environment6) then
    raise Exception.Create('IID_ICoreWebView2Environment6 not found - necessary CreatePrintSettings support lacking');

  // Create print settings
  Environment6.CreatePrintSettings(PrintSettings);
  if not Assigned(PrintSettings) then
    raise Exception.Create('PrintSettings not found');

  // Check that the currently installed version of WebView2
  // supports print settings interface version 2 (which has the Copies property, among other things)
  PrintSettings.QueryInterface(IID_ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2, PrintSettings2);
  if not Assigned(PrintSettings2) then
    raise Exception.Create('IID_ICoreWebView2PrintSettings2 not found - necessary Copies support lacking');

  //
  // Now everything that we need seems to be in place - go on with actual printing
  //

  // Set the wanted number of copies (could also set other settings here)
  PrintSettings2.Set_Copies(Copies);
  // Maybe ask for grayscale printing
  if GrayScale then
    PrintSettings2.Set_ColorMode(COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_COLOR_MODE_GRAYSCALE);

  // Since this variable is of interface type, the object will get auto-Freed
  CompletedHandler := TCompletedHandler.Create;

  HR := Core2_16.Print(PrintSettings2, CompletedHandler);
  if not Succeeded(HR) then
    raise Exception.Create('ICoreWebView2_16.Print failed');
end;

{ TCompletedHandler }

function TCompletedHandler.Invoke(errorCode: HResult;
  printStatus: COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_STATUS): HResult;
var
  ResultStatus: TPrintStatus;
begin
  case printStatus of
    COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_STATUS_SUCCEEDED:  ResultStatus := psSucceeded;
    COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_STATUS_PRINTER_UNAVAILABLE:  ResultStatus := psPrinterUnavailable;
    COREWEBVIEW2_PRINT_STATUS_OTHER_ERROR:  ResultStatus := psOtherError;
  else
    ResultStatus := psUnknown;
  end;

  CallWhenDonePrinting(errorCode, ResultStatus);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

TEdgeBrowser uses an old WebView2 version. Consider using [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi) and you'll be able to set the TWVBrowser.CoreWebView2PrintSettings.Copies property value and then simply call TWVBrowser.Print.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to upgrade the version of WebView2 that TEdgeBrowser uses?

Comment: @KyleWilliamson That's not easy to do. Some people have upgraded the imported type library but that's only a small fraction of the work. You would still need to implement all the missing features and that's not always possible with a closed source component like TEdgeBrowser. Alessandro Mancini also published the AMEdgeBrowser project which extends the current TEdgeBrowser component. https://github.com/amancini/AMEdgeBrowser

Comment: It's not much help, but this is one reason to stick with standard Delphi components rather than Microsoft's -- MS is constantly deprecating their interfaces and replacing them with newer ones, and backward compatibility has never been something they care much about. For Delphi, however, that's a key feature; sometimes it means that components based on specific MS DLLs and OCXs don't get updated for a LONG TIME, if ever. But it also means that after 10 years and many MS updates, a Delphi app in the newest rev will still compile and work with those older MS parts that not even MS supports!

Comment: RAD Studio 12.0 refreshed the WebView 2 control API to a recent version, WebView2 SDK 1.0.1774.30. This brings support for many new features of the underlying WebView 2 control